# How to create the Apple Certificate file

Tags: ios

Referring to https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/building-cordova-ios-apps-intel-xdk.

It says: "Upload the CSR file to the Apple website to create the Apple Certificate file."

I registered in apple developers. But I can't find the location to which the file should be uploaded.

Can anyone help me.

**Hope this question is in the right site.**

Answer (score 1):

First, Is this for the Apple Store OR solely for some intel xdk platform stuff?

If you have access to your apple developer's account:   go to managing my certificate /apps and create the CSR there then upload it on BOTH your local machine AND intel /apple developer consoles for signing purposes.While marked as a 10.6 Server article it is still used in the current Xcode : (use this to create Certificate and subsequent CSR and upload that..  [Creating a Certificate with Apple and Generating a CSR](https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT3976)